# What is the difference between IsAdmin and IsAdminInstallMode in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

What is the real difference between:

- [`IsAdminInstallMode`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_isadmininstallmode)
- [`IsAdmin`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_isadmininstallmode)

I read the help but don't really get it:

> `IsAdminInstallMode`: Returns `True` if Setup is running in
> administrative install mode or if Uninstall is running with
> administrative privileges.
>
> `IsAdmin`: Returns `True` if Setup/Uninstall
> is running with administrative privileges.

What is the difference between *administrative install* / *administrative privileges*?

I am asking because when building I received this warning:

> Warning: Line 118, Column 6: [Hint] Support function "IsAdminLoggedOn" has been renamed. Use "IsAdmin" instead or consider using "IsAdminInstallMode".

Which should I use and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the documentation says, the [`IsAdminInstallMode`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_isadmininstallmode) *returns True if Setup is running in [administrative install mode](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=admininstallmode).* Where the administrative install mode means:

> - The `{group}` folder is created in the *All Users* profile.
> - The "auto" form of the directory and Shell Folder constants is mapped to the "common" form.
> - The HKA, uninstall info, and font install root keys will be HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.

Whether administrator install mode is used depends on the [`PrivilegesRequired` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_privilegesrequired) (and in recent versions also by [`PrivilegesRequiredOverridesAllowed`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_privilegesrequiredoverridesallowed)). You basically use these directives to declare, if the installer needs (or can make use of) the Administrator privileges.

---

While the [`IsAdmin`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_isadmin) (aka `IsAdminLoggedOn`) is true, if the installer has been executed with administrator privileges. So that's something the user controls, not the installer.

---

| IsAdminLoggedOn | IsAdminInstallMode | Meaning |
| --- | --- | --- |
| True | True | The installer was executed with administrator privileges, and uses them to install the application for all users. |
| True | False | The installer was executed with administrator privileges, but does not need them and will still install the application for the current user only. |
| False | False | The installer was not executed with administrator privileges, and does not need them as it will install the application for the current user only. |
| False | True | *Not possible.* |

---

The `IsAdmin` is an equivalent of `IsAdminLoggedOn`. But usually, you actually want `IsAdminInstallMode`, not `IsAdminLoggedOn`. That's why the function was renamed and split into these two. It depends on what you test for.